# open a modal which reside inside a remote page from parent page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I Want to open a remote page's modal from anchor of some other page.

Suppose I have a page like index in which the anchor tag has some id and in href m passing the url of other page but i need to open a modal having an id resides in the url page

Comment: Can't you pass something in request string and then in javascript check for that and open modal?

Comment: actually it is working fine it is opening the modal which i want but it is taking bit time like it is first opening the whole page like for a fraction of second then it is opening the modal which i want and 1 more thng i jus need only that particular div content but rest of the thing is also showng in inspect element